# sforce is not defined in winter 16

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-platform

I am getting the following error in my visualforce page available for mobile, where using the sforce variable :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: sforce is not defined
```

Prior to the winter 16 release everything were working fine. On my iphone the code works, but it is no more working when accessing the page in my browser on my desktop. I suspect that it's because i didn't activated the new salesforce1 interfaces (lightning experience). Because i'm not using one/one.app either because of this limitation impose by salesforce. But i need to access my page via desktop on my browser for javascript debuging purposes. How can i get to use the sforce variables wihtout activating lightning experience for my user ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a very nice tool that replaces the one/one.app to test for mobile visualforce page on the web. It is actually a plugin on chrome web store name salesforce1 simulator. From there it works like a charm. But i can't debug the code if the js crashes. Then i do as suggested, using an emulator on my chrome browser, then i launched the one/one.app (no lightning in the url) and inspect using the chrome inspect element.

Answer (score 6):

> Switching agent of your browser can easily load the emulator (remember
>   don't need to enable Lightning for this, neither sharing rule), you can
>   change browser agent in chrome/safari manually, or simply use
>   agent-switch plugin to change agent to mobile

Agent Switch: (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US)

and using this URL (enter your domain):
DOMAIN.lightning.force.com/one/one.app

reference: http://www.oyecode.com/2015/10/winter-16-fix-salesforce1-oneoneapp.html

Comment: my custom domain is mytest--dev2--c.cs20 and i rebuild the url as mention but failed to load : https://mytest--dev2--c.cs20.lightning.force.com/one/one.app. note : i'm using custom domain name with sso enabled.

Answer (score 5):

The one/one app is no longer available for Salesforce1 as of Winter16. See the [Release Notes](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter16.jsp). You'll need to use an emulator as discussed in the notes. In my experience, you can typically use Chrome in mobile mode device emulation mode for most of your needs, but I've not used it recently to see if it's still working for non-lightning pages.

Comment: Chrome browsers still work after switching the user agent with the dev tools! Just echoing other responses here, and pointing toward some Salesforce docs that may help:     https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-does-Salesforce1-Mobile-browser-app-does-not-work-on-a-Desktop-Web-Browser&language=en_US     http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/CZvCWa2tG9TmradIkVyJgw

Comment: yes this works too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding references to JS files

{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/34.0/apex.js")}

Worked for me